# Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have installed a latest `maven-3.2.5` on Linux Mint Throgh CLi
The installation details are as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
export M2_HOME=/home/mani/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/
```

In the command  it shows it like this:

```
mani@manithullimilli ~/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin $ ./mvn version
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher mani@manithullimilli
>   ~/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin $

I Have Setted Path Also

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mentioned M2_HOME environment variable incorrectly.M2_HOME environment variable should be "**/home/mani/apache-maven-3.2.5**"

```
export M2_HOME=/home/mani/apache-maven-3.2.5
```

and Add the **$M2_HOME/bin** directory to your path.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an export somewhere you are not aware of.

Check all places where environment variables are defined, e.g.

```
    /etc/environment
    ~/.bashrc
    ~/.mavenrc
```

In my case `.mavenrc` was pointing to my old maven's home, I deleted it and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, installed maven, everything was correct but was still getting "could not find class" error.

After I ran : source /etc/environment

everything worked after that. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

For some reason `CLASSWORLDS_JAR` system variable was empty.

This worked for me:

Defined this system variable with value `%MAVEN_HOME%\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2`,